# Make sentences with 1st|2nd|3rd|4th to XML according to a special specification

Tags: python, xml

I want to make those sentences to xml

```
I will meet you at 1st.
5th... OK, 5th?
today is 2nd\n
Aug.3rd
```

Like this:

```
<Text VAlign="top" VPosition="85.00">
    I will meet you at 1<Font Script="super">st</Font>.
</Text>
<Text VAlign="top" VPosition="85.00">
    5<Font Script="super">th</Font>... OK, 5<Font Script="super">th</Font>
</Text>
<Text VAlign="top" VPosition="85.00">
        today is 2<Font Script="super">nd</Font>\n
</Text>
<Text VAlign="top" VPosition="85.00">
        Aug.3<Font Script="super">rd</Font>\n
</Text>
```

I am using the minidom, but after many posts and answers, I don't mind rewrite my code with other parser. At the beginning, I thought this is easy, just replace the `st|nd|rd|th` with

`<Font Script="super">st|nd|rd|th</Font>` and then createTextNode() with this new string.

However, the sign `<, > and "` turn out to be `&lt; &gt; and $quot;` by writexml() method. which works for XML specification, but not good for read.

How can I do with it? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you can do with [xml.etree.ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) from the standard library:

```
import re
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


data = """I will meet you at 1st.
5th... OK, 5th?
today is 2nd
Aug.3rd"""

endings = ['st', 'th', 'nd', 'rd']
pattern = re.compile('(%s)' % "|".join(endings))

root = ET.Element('root')
for line in data.split('\n'):
    items = []
    for item in re.split(pattern, line):
        if item in endings:
            items.append('<Font Script="super">%s</Font>' % item)
        else:
            items.append(item)
    element = ET.fromstring("""<Text VAlign="top" VPosition="85.00">%s</Text>""" % ''.join(items))
    root.append(element)

print ET.tostring(root)
```

It produces the following xml:

```
<root>
    <Text VAlign="top" VPosition="85.00">I will meet you at 1<Font Script="super">st</Font>.
    </Text>
    <Text VAlign="top" VPosition="85.00">5<Font Script="super">th</Font>... OK, 5<Font Script="super">th</Font>?
    </Text>
    <Text VAlign="top" VPosition="85.00">today is 2
        <Font Script="super">nd</Font>
    </Text>
    <Text VAlign="top" VPosition="85.00">Aug.3
        <Font Script="super">rd</Font>
    </Text>
</root>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I don't have indents and newline for my output , my environment: Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Nov 22 2013, 12:11:10) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4)] on linux2

Answer (score 0):

To make the output with propel indent and newline, I need the lxml, and I put this in alecxe's code.

```
from lxml import etree as ET

print ET.tostring(root, pretty_print=True)
```